# __func__ outside function definition

Tags: c++, c, c++11, c99, c11

What should happened if we use predefined variable `__func__` outside a function in C (C99 / C11) and C++?

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char* str = __func__;

int main(void)
{
   printf("%s", str);
   return 0;
}
```

gcc 4.7.2 only give a warning (with `-Wall -W -pedantic` enabled) and prints nothing.

Standard doesn't say anything about it explicitly:

**ISO/IEC 14882:2011**

8.4.1 In general [dcl.fct.def.general]

> **8** The function-local predefined variable `__func__` is defined as if a
>   definition of the form `static const char __func__[] = "function-name";`
>   had been provided, where function-name is an implementation-defined
>   string. It is unspecified whether such a variable has an address
>   distinct from that of any other object in the program.

**ISO/IEC 9899:2011**

6.4.2.2 Predefined identifiers

> **1** The identifier `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the translator as if, immediately
>   following the opening brace of each function definition, the
>   declaration `static const char __func__[] = "function-name";`
>   appeared, where function-name is the name of the lexically-enclosing
>   function.

UB? Error? Or something else?

Comment: I vote for error, given the wording "function-local predefined variable" and "immediately following the opening brace of each function definition" in your quotations.

Comment: Any behaviour not defined by the standard is, by elimination, undefined behaviour ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Standard doesn't say anything about it explicitly

This means undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (emphasis mine):

> (C99, 4.p2) "If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears outside of a constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined. Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this International Standard by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ **or by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior.** There is no difference in emphasis among these three; they all describe ‘‘behavior that is undefined’’."

Answer (score 7):

(Promoted from an earlier comment)

`__func__` is in the reserved namespace, so the implementation is allowed to use it at namespace scope for any purpose, i.e. the implementation is not required to diagnose a (mis)use of `__func__` outside a function, because nothing in the standard forbids an implementation from defining `__func__` as a namespace-scope array of `char` if that's what the implementors want to do.

It could be undefined, or it could be defined as a string, or as anything else, and that implementation is still conforming.

So it's undefined behaviour to try to use it outside a function because it may or may not be defined and may or may not be of the right type to be usable.

For concrete examples of how the code in the question could have undefined behaviour when used with a conforming implementation, I believe an implementation could define it to `nullptr` (so the example would crash in `printf`) or could even define it to a macro that expands to a dereference of a null pointer and then `#undef` it on entry to each function and `#define` it after each function (so the example would crash before `main` begins!)

Comment: +1 for a thorough explanation instead of a pedantic citation only .